# Dwarf Fortress sound

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Every time I start the game the sound is at 255/255. Is there any way to make it start at a different level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your init file, you can turn sound off by default with `[SOUND:NO]` or set the sound to a specific volume with `[VOLUME:100]` or whatever level you want. The init file can be found in the Dwarf Fortress folder under data/init/init.txt

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your `init` files.